# SQL Server BACPAC Import fails with IDENTITY_INSERT error

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I'm importing a bacpac from Azure to a local SQL DB.  The process goes for a while and on about the 50th table it fails with this error:

IDENTITY_INSERT is already on for table 'X'.
Cannot perform set operation for table 'Y'

Table 'X' was successfully processed already (it was like table #45 in the list).
Table 'Y' is the one currently processing (like table #50 in the list).

After the error/failure I see rows on table Y so it seems at one point IDENTITY_INSERT was ON for that table.  Not sure what else to check.

Comment: This seems to be a bug.  The workaround is to import using sqlpackage.exe and use the option /MaxParallelism:1 .  Seems the bug is related to when it uses multiple threads to import the bacpac.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround use the Import/Export Wizard instead. After selecting the source and destination tables, click on edit mappings. In the resultant pop-up, click on edit SQL and edit the auto-generated SQL and add IDENTITY (1,1) at the end of the column you want to set IDENTITY property. Ensure that you have enabled IDENTITY INSERT ON by checking the relevant box.